# How to put multiple features into RNN input vector

Tags: python, neural-network, rnn, feature-construction

I am trying to code a recurrent neural network (LSTM) to create music in python and was considering using multiple features instead of just the note pitch as an input into the network. Initially I had just the note pitch so it was fed into the network by one-hot encoding it. The other two features I want to add are the note duration and the offset between the notes. How should the input vector be organised so that all the data is fed through the network?

I have tried combining all of the data into a long vector with all 3 features one-hot encoded and then concatenated but this caused the output to become 'NaN'. Any help would be appreciated.

Link a gist of my code:

https://gist.github.com/treutm/1b1f49e3d0a9de53cd67c136292f329f

Comment: which deep learning library are you using? tensor-flow or pytorch? Also for this type of question, please include your code in the question.

Comment: @LouisT I’m using a numpy implementation of an LSTM should I just put the code for forward propagation?

Comment: The NaN can occur at backdrop as well. If your code is too long, put it in a gist on GitHub and include a link to it.

Comment: @LouisT Just added the link to the gist. Just checking, can you view it? (haven't made a gist before)

Comment: congrats on your first gist :)  and yes, I can see the gist. Can you try to modify this code such that someone can simply copy the code and run it on their machine to reproduce the NaN you are seeing? You might need to save the output your `read_mini` in another gist.

Comment: @LouisT I updated the code so it can be run but how do I add the music files to the gist?

Comment: on your line 45 `data,durations,offsets = read_midi('./Downloads/*.mid')`. Instead of doing this, you can manually construct the `data`, `duration`, `offset`? This is called mocking or stubbing in testing. This might help with your debugging process in general as well. As this will allow you to see what kind of kinds will cause the error to raise.

Comment: @LouisT I added mock results to the gist and it looks like all the calculated probabilities in the forward step recur to 0 (1.2e-159) so the loss becomes extreme highly but this doesn't happen when I only have a single one-hot feature.

Comment: @treutum, great, you code failed at L51 `unique_offsets = sorted(list(set(offsets)))`
offsets is a float, I believe it should be an ndarray?

Comment: @LouisT My mistake I have made it into an array and should now run.

Comment: Glanced over the code, the `forward_backward` doesn't look right to me. It looks like you are accumulating all of the loss occurred in all steps before doing the backprops. So, you are doing 1 backprops every iteration (epoch). Is that correct?  If so, then that's wrong. You need to do the backprops at every step. So 32427 - 1  backprops per epoch.

Comment: @LouisT The backprop should run on every step, it runs through the sequence in forward propagation then backwards through the sequence in the second part of forward backward. Does it not?

Comment: t0 => forward => t1_pred => loss(t1_pred, t1) => backprops, t1 => forward => t2_pred => loss(t2_pred, t2) => backprops, .....

Comment: It's be clear with the terminolgy here.A **batch** of data contains a number of **series** of data, each **series** contains multiple **steps**. In you example, you are not doing batch at all, so you won't have that dimension. You have `data = np.random.randint(0,251,(32427))` . This is one series with 32427 steps

Comment: I assume you have a reason for doing this by hand in numpy. Using a deep learning library could save you a lot of trouble otherwise.

Comment: @LouisT The data is split into batches during the training step

Comment: okay I see what you did there regarding the batches. But the problem is still the same. Don't forward through the entire series, then backprops. Do it one time steps at a time

Comment: Recurrent neural net in general, take the input at t to predict input at t+1. If you want to do this in a single backprops for the entire series (as are you doing it now), you need to do what is called `unrolling` the RNN.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/rnn-unrolling/ have a read of this, see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to input several features to an LSTM (or any RNN) is, as you did, to concatenate them in a vector. I suspect your NaN are related to a different issue in the code, and I recommend you to debug it and see when and why it happens.

A different way of combining several features is using embeddings for each feature and combine them via concatenation. For example, for the note pitch, you have an embedding for each note, for the note duration, the same, and so on. The input to the RNN would be a concatenation of that.

A third option would be to have an embedding to all possible combinations of the embeddings. That would be an embedding for each triplet of note pitch, note duration and offset. This representation can be also powerful.

My recommendation is that you start with the easiest to implement, and if the result is not satisfactory in terms of model performance, think about the next one.